# Pokemon Go - PVP Status after massive Power Up

Tags: pokemon-go

So, If I have a pokemon that has 97% good status for PVP, and I go over 2500 CP, does it loses its good stats for PVP?

I'm asking that because I have a good pokemon, with 90 IV and 97% stats for PVP, and I'd like to use it against Giovanni.

But I need to power it up, and I wonder if keeping it at 2490 is gonna do any good agains Giovanni's Persian that has a CP over 7k or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its 97% stat is for a specific league, in your case it seems the 2500CP or Ultra League. Powering it above 2500CP makes it ineligible for that league. If you want to keep using it in PvP, do *not* power it up!

In more general, the best IV changes per cup per Pokemon. Take for example Swampert, a Pokemon that is doing very well in each League, has a perfect PvP IV of 0/14/14 in the Great League, a perfect PvP IV of 0/14/13 in the Ultra League, and in the Master League obviously 15/15/15. So the 97% for PvP changes from league to league.

Comment: A more general tip, in case you have excess good Pokemon and candy+stardust, it is good to have different sets of Pokemon for raiding/team rocket and PvP. This is because for raiding the attack stat (and level) should be as high as possible, for PvP it is in most cases better to have a lower attack IV

Comment: To OP, see [Do IVs matter in the PvP battle league?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/365239/124566) for info regarding IVs in different leagues

Comment: @Wondercricket oh yeah, I had to find a different example there for the Perfect IV vs Perfect PvP IV. Doing that now :)

Comment: So Team Rocket needs Pokemons good for Gyms.... not PVP. That makes sense.

Comment: @MarceloHenriquesCortez Actually, Team Rocket needs both. There's no CP restriction, so you want 100% IVs in all cases (unlike PvP), BUT it uses PvPs battle system and move changes, so some extremely strong moves in PvE are outclassed in PvP. Specifically, charge moves that require very little energy are extremely strong against Rockets, despite often being a weaker option in gyms/raids.